# How to test MySQL event scheduler?

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I created an event that runs once every week. I want to test this event, but of course, I don't want to wait the entire week.

How can I test this event? Best practices?

Comment: set it to run once an hour/minute. if that works, then it should also work when you change it back to weekly. coarse hack: set the system clock ahead 6.9999 days

Comment: @Strawberry I've done this. But I was wondering if there's another way to test. I want to see how the community does this, so it's not a dumb question.

Comment: @MarcB i tested for 10 second yes it working fine but tested one month i just tested change date in my local computer doesn't give me anything ? how can i test event about one month, thanks